# Hibernate Criteria - how can you limit child classes returned?

Tags: hibernate

I have a very rich hierarchy of entity classes. I'm trying to restrict the results in some queries to only those of a certain list of entity classes. I'm doing the following...

```
    detachedCriteria.add(Restrictions.disjunction().
            add(Restrictions.eq("class", FabricData.class)).
            add(Restrictions.eq("class", HostData.class)).
            add(Restrictions.eq("class", StorageSystemBase.class)).
            add(Restrictions.eq("class", SwitchData.class))
    );
```

However, I'm getting the error...

```
[testng-wrapper] java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
[testng-wrapper]        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.IntegerTypeDescriptor.unwrap(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:36)
```

So how can I list the subclasses I want from the query?

-Robert

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate - Restriction for class in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996512/hibernate-restriction-for-class-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have used a Discriminator...

The way you've tried is possible through HQL but for Criteria you need to specify the discriminator value instead of the Class:

```
detachedCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("class", "FABRICDATA_DISCRIMINATOR"));
```